# Recorte em imagem

Tags: delphi

Tenho um `TForm`, e nesse form um componente `TImage` com uma imagem qualquer. O que eu quero é selecionar uma parte com o mouse dessa imagem, e na sequência uma função que faça um "buraco" na imagem e no form.

Resumindo, eu passo as coordenadas X,Y e é feito um "buraco" na imagem e no form para eu ver por trás.

Comment: Cara, colocar um "buraco" no form, é meio estranho. Para que você quer fazer isso ?

Comment: Insira o código que estás utilizando.